# Optimize matrix multiplication when one matrix is the same.

Tags: matrices, linear-programming

I have a situation where I will be multiplying $AB\vec{x}$ together frequently. $A$ is a 4x4 matrix that won't change from problem to problem. $B$ is a 4x4 matrix that will change occasionally, and $\vec{x}$ is a 3d vector, $[x,y,z,1]$ that will be different from problem to problem.

I would like to optimize to take less multiplication operations, and I think I remember a factorization from linear algebra that could accomplish this but have forgotten the name of it. Is there such a factorization?

Comment: It sounds like you're just multiplying things. Are you actually trying to *solve* for anything (like $\vec{x}$) in some sort of system? For example, would you be solving for $\vec{x}$ in the expression $AB\vec{x} = \vec{d}$ where $A,B,\vec{d}$ are known but $\vec{x}$ is unknown?

Comment: @Xoque55 Nope, just doing the mutliplcation

Comment: In that case, there's really no way to get around doing the multiplications and additions. However, you can express the result of the whole process as a single $4\times 1$ vector whose components depend on $A,B,\vec{x}$. Although $4 \times 4$ matrix products are tractable to "hard-code" like that, it would be still be a fair amount of work that is captured rather elegantly with the expression for matrix multiplication. Do you understand what I mean by "hard-coding" the elements of the resultant vector?

Comment: @Xoque55 I am guess that means to rather than actually do the matrix multiplication hard code the answer, i.e. $[A_1_1 * B_1_1 + A_1_2 * B_21$...., but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had in mind.